# How conver string of numbers to time using date-fns?

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs, date-fns

Using date-fns, how it could be converted string like '2223' to time '22:23' using date-fns? I tried use **parse** method but it return 'Invalid Date'

```
const timeString = '2223';
parse(timeString, 'HH:mm', new Date())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your template string says it has a `:` in the input string which your `timeString` doesnt, so you either have to change your `timeString` to `22:23` or change your parse method to template to this: `HHmm`

Comment: I get timeString from input value

Comment: Then you should write some validation logic as checking if it has 2 numbers, double point and 2 numbers otherwise tell user input is invalid

Comment: Or use something like `timeString.replace(':','')` and always parse it as HHmm, or `timeString.match(/\d\d/g).join(':')` and always parse it as HH:mm. Or…